# Manipulating 3D models using Matlab to create specified Voids

Tags: matlab, pde, 3d-modelling, 3d-model

I am working to create a basic model of bubbles within a static cube of water to test the electric field generated between an ideal system of parallel plates. I am currently using the PDEToolbox included with matlab so am working with DiscreteGeometries. I have also been tinkering with importing a cube and bubbles as .stl files from CAD software and pairing them. I wish to control the location/size of the blocks such as those used in this [example](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/sphere-in-cube.html). I wish to create 'bubbles' so just changing the shape/size/location of the sphere used would be great!
Is this feasible using matlab at all? Either of the methods stated above would be best unless there is a more applicable way to do this more simply.

Comment: how do you want to "tag" the cavity\bubble? as missing indices in the grid? as zeros?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the example you gave to show how you can create bubbles by eliminating grid points from the cube gird:

```
% create the "cube"
[xg, yg, zg] = meshgrid(-2:0.25:2);
Pcube = [xg(:) yg(:), zg(:)];
```

make a "helper" function to only consider the x,y,z indices of a sphere keeping
only the grid points above some radius r

```
bubble = @(x,y,z,r) vecnorm(bsxfun(@minus,Pcube',[x y z]')) > r;
```

Now we can create the "bubbles" by eliminating grid points in the cube according to the "bubble" function above

```
Pcavitycube = Pcube( bubble(0.5, 0.8, 1.1, 0.25) & ...
                     bubble( 1 ,-0.2, 0.1, 0.4 ) & ...
                     bubble( -1,-0.8,  -1, 0.7 ) ...
                     ,:);

plot(alphaShape(Pcavitycube),'FaceAlpha',0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: I love this response, this is exactly what I was aiming for, is there a way to make the proposed model more spherical, I know this is nit-picking as the model made is already very good, however when producing a PDEmodel from this mesh, the shapes made are a little bit inconsistent.

Comment: apologies, I have simply increased the resolution of the model, which i thought may be the route of said cause due to the tetrhedral model of the 'bubbles' which has mostly resolved the issue.